# Pcap4j return null packets header depending on runtime environment

Tags: java, weka, pcap4j

I'm actually developing a contextual data generator for Weka and I package it as a Weka plugins (using the templates here: https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/tree/master/packages/templates).

A part of my plugins is to reading data from a pcap file so I'm using the pcap4j library. Here my problem start, while I'm in my dev environment the pcap file are well parsed and my plugins works but when I'm in a basic "prod" env the pcap reader doesn't read well the pcap file and return a null header for each packets.

### Dev environment

Maven project

Java:

```bash
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In my dev env, I'm working with the Weka-3-8-6 source code, recompile it and running it with the following command:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java @/tmp/cp_1784hdtalynu1dcgm6jy5m4n0.argfile weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

Then I can import my zipped plugins and try it (it works well).

### Prod environment

To test my plugins in real context environment (without recompiling Weka), I'm downloading the Weka-3.8.6 release, running it, importing my plugins and the trying my data generator. Here are the problem, the pcap packets headers values are all at null. First I checked the pcap file, but it hasn't change from the dev environment so the problem come from the runtime environment but I dont know why.

Good to know that Weka come with it's own JRE: `weka-3-8-6/jre/zulu17.32.13-ca-fx-jre17.0.2-linux_x64`

### The plugins

My plugins is compiled with ant, following the [Weka plugins templates](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/tree/master/packages/templates). Here is the compile command:

```bash
$ ant make_package -Dpackage <MY_PLUGINS>
```

And here is the related make package instruction from the `build.xml`:

```xml
<!-- Compile the java code from ${src}/weka into ${build}/classes -->
  <target name="compile" depends="init_compile"
    description="Compile package and deposit class files in build/classes">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src}"
      fork="yes" memoryMaximumSize="${javac_max_memory}"
      destdir="${build}/classes"
      optimize="${optimization}"
      debug="${debug}"
      deprecation="${deprecation}"
      source="1.6" target="1.6">
      <!-- Import lib dependencies -->
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
          <include name="*.jar" />
          <include name="*.zip" />
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${build}/classes">
      <fileset dir="${src}">
        <include name="**/*.gif" />
        <include name="**/*.png" />
        <include name="**/*.jpeg" />
        <include name="**/*.jpg" />
        <include name="**/*.props" />
        <include name="**/*.txt" />
        <include name="**/*.xml" />
        <include name="**/*.cup" />
        <include name="**/*.flex" />
        <include name="**/*.jflex" />
        <include name="**/*.properties" />
        <include name="**/*.default" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

<!-- Put everything in ${build}/classes into the ${package}.jar file -->
<target name="exejar" depends="compile, docs, init_dist"
  description="Create a binary jar file in ./dist">
  <jar jarfile="${dist}/${package}.jar
    basedir="${build}/classes">
  </jar>
</target>

<target name="make_package" depends="clean, exejar"
    description="Make the package zip file. Run with -Dpackage=[package name]">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/${package}" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/${package}">
      <fileset dir="${dist}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <delete>
      <fileset dir="${dist}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </delete>
    <copy file="Description.props"
      todir="${dist}/${package}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/${package}/lib" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/${package}/lib">
      <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        <include name="*.zip" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/${package}/doc" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/${package}/doc">
      <fileset dir="${doc}">
        <include name="**/*" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/${package}/src" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/${package}">
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="*.xml" />
        <include name="src/**/*.excludes" />
        <include name="src/**/*.gif" />
        <include name="src/**/*.java" />
        <include name="src/**/*.jpeg" />
        <include name="src/**/*.jpg" />
        <include name="src/**/*.props" />
        <include name="src/**/*.txt" />
        <include name="src/**/*.xml" />
        <include name="src/**/*.cup" />
        <include name="src/**/*.flex" />
        <include name="src/**/*.jflex" />
        <include name="src/**/*.properties" />
        <include name="src/**/*.default" />
        <include name="src/**/*.cost" />
        <include name="src/**/*.arff" />
        <include name="src/**/*.matrix" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <zip destfile="${dist}/${package}.zip"
      basedir="${dist}/${package}">
    </zip>
  </target>
```

### Test

1. I trying to run my home compiled Weka (dev env) with the jre provided by Weka-3.8.6 (jre used in prod env) but still have the same issue.

```bash
$ /usr/bin/env /home/marc-andre/weka-3-8-6/jre/zulu17.32.13-ca-fx-jre17.0.2-linux_x64/bin/java @/tmp/cp_1784hdtalynu1dcgm6jy5m4n0.argfile weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

2. I compared the JAVA class path (by adding `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` ), but I'm not such an Java expert so I don't really know what I can concluded. Here are the output:

Dev env:

```
/home/marc-andre/data/ContackGen/Weka/build/classes:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/vbmacher/java-cup/11b-20160615/java-cup-11b-20160615.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/vbmacher/java-cup-runtime/11b-20160615/java-cup-runtime-11b-20160615.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/nz/ac/waikato/cms/weka/thirdparty/bounce/0.18/bounce-0.18.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.1/okhttp-4.9.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/2.8.0/okio-2.8.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.0/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/mtj-1.0.4.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/native_ref-java/1.1/native_ref-java-1.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/jniloader/1.1/jniloader-1.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-linux-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_ref-linux-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-linux-i686/1.1/netlib-native_ref-linux-i686-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-win-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_ref-win-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-win-i686/1.1/netlib-native_ref-win-i686-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_ref-linux-armhf/1.1/netlib-native_ref-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-osx-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_system-osx-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/native_system-java/1.1/native_system-java-1.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-linux-i686/1.1/netlib-native_system-linux-i686-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-linux-armhf/1.1/netlib-native_system-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-win-x86_64/1.1/netlib-native_system-win-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-win-i686/1.1/netlib-native_system-win-i686-1.1-natives.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/f2j/arpack_combined_all/0.1/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/netlib-java/netlib-java/1.1/netlib-java-1.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/core/1.1/core-1.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fracpete/jfilechooser-bookmarks/0.1.6/jfilechooser-bookmarks-0.1.6.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/fracpete/jclipboardhelper/0.1.0/jclipboardhelper-0.1.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.12/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.5/jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.5/txw2-2.3.5.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/formdev/flatlaf/2.0/flatlaf-2.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java/3.3.0/docker-java-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java-core/3.3.0/docker-java-core-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java-api/3.3.0/docker-java-api-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.3/jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java-transport/3.3.0/docker-java-transport-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.3/jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.3/jackson-core-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.64/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.64/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java-transport-jersey/3.3.0/docker-java-transport-jersey-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.10.3/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.10.3/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.10.3/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/connectors/jersey-apache-connector/2.30.1/jersey-apache-connector-2.30.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.30.1/jersey-common-2.30.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.3/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.12/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.30.1/jersey-client-2.30.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/jakarta.inject/2.6.1/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/inject/jersey-hk2/2.30.1/jersey-hk2-2.30.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.6.1/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.6.1/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.6.1/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.6.1/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.25.0-GA/javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/kohlschutter/junixsocket/junixsocket-common/2.6.1/junixsocket-common-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/kohlschutter/junixsocket/junixsocket-native-common/2.6.1/junixsocket-native-common-2.6.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/com/github/docker-java/docker-java-transport-netty/3.3.0/docker-java-transport-netty-3.3.0.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.46.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.46.Final/netty-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.46.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.46.Final/netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.46.Final/netty-codec-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.46.Final/netty-handler-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.46.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.46.Final/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.46.Final/netty-codec-socks-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.46.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.46.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.46.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.46.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.46.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.30/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/pcap4j/pcap4j-core/1.8.2/pcap4j-core-1.8.2.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.3.1/jna-5.3.1.jar:/home/marc-andre/.m2/repository/org/pcap4j/pcap4j-packetfactory-static/1.8.2/pcap4j-packetfactory-static-1.8.2.jar
```

and prod Env:

```bash
/home/marc-andre/weka-3-8-6/weka.jar
```

Does someone know what could affect the correct functioning of pcap4j ?